# Filter not returning results if lower levels doesnt match unless the high level match

Tags: android, kotlin, search

The code below is supposed to search for any match in chapter name, section name, subsection name, or paragraph content, but unfortunately, it only returns results if the chapter name matches, meaning that if the paragraph content matches, it ignores the entire chapter as it didn't match the chapter name.

Below is the filtering code:

```
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val query = constraint.toString().lowercase()
                searchTextQuery=query
                val filteredData = if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    originalList
                } else {
                    originalList.filter { chapter ->
                        chapter.name.lowercase().contains(query) ||
                                chapter.sectionList?.any { section ->
                                    section.name.lowercase().contains(query) ||
                                            section.subsectionList?.any { subsection ->
                                                subsection.name.lowercase().contains(query) ||
                                                        subsection.paragraphList?.any { 
paragraph->paragraph.name.lowercase().contains(query)
                                                        } == true
                                            } == true
                                } == true
                    }
                }

                val results = FilterResults()
                results.values = filteredData
                return results
       }

       override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                if (results!= null && results.values is List<*>) {
                    filteredList = results.values as List<Chapter>
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
       }
   }
}
```

Here are the Models:

```
@Parcelize
data class Book(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
    @SerializedName("chapters") var chapters: List<Chapter>?
): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Chapter(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("ctitle") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("sections") var sectionList: MutableList<Section>? = null,
    @SerializedName("bookId") var bookId: String?,
    @SerializedName("cnumber") var number: String?,
    var isExpanded: Boolean = false
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Section(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("title") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("chapterId") var chapterId: String?,
    @SerializedName("sectionnum") var sectionnum: String?,
    @SerializedName("subsections") var subsectionList: MutableList<SubSection>? = null,
    @SerializedName("paragraphs") var paragraphList: MutableList<Paragraph>? = null,
    var cleanedParagraphs:MutableList<Paragraph>? = null,
    var isExpanded: Boolean = false
): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class SubSection(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("title") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("chapterId") var chapterId: String?,
    @SerializedName("subsectionnum") var sectionnum: String?,
    @SerializedName("paragraphs") var paragraphList: MutableList<Paragraph>? = null,
    var cleanedParagraphs:MutableList<Paragraph>?= null,
    var isExpanded: Boolean = false
): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Paragraph(
    @SerializedName("content") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("sectionId") var sectionId: String?,
    @SerializedName("sectionnum") val sectionnum: String?,
    @SerializedName("subsectionId") var subsectionId: String?,
    var isExpanded: Boolean = false
):Parcelable
```

Comment: It didnt work sir

Comment: What did you find? Was sectionList present? If you set break points at the inner levels are the reached? What if you do something really simple like delete everything after `section.name.lowercase().contains(query)` starting at || so that you just focus on filtering by paragraph and section and nothing else?

Comment: Thank you, actually am new to android studio, i need to learn debugging tools in it, thanks

Comment: You can just add print(“hello 1”) and print(“hello 2”) through out your code to see what is reached

Answer (score 0):

Your code has short-circuiting set up correctly. Since it is A || (B || C), then iff A is true then it will stop and automatically include the results, otherwise it will try to go deeper.

Try setting a breakpoint here though, to see if the code is being reached:

```
    chapter.sectionList?.any { section ->
```

Because likely the sectionList of every chapter is not what you expect. They may be null:

```
    @SerializedName("sections") var sectionList: MutableList<Section>? = null,
```